# Deployed Laravel app to shared hosting and get a "500 | Server Error"

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

Allow me to preface this by saying that yes, I have looked at the other similar questions regarding this and while they had a problem intrinsically linked to their code mine is completely fine on my local machine. With that said, I deployed a [Laravel e-commerce store](https://shushop.derickmasai.com) to my shared hosting account while following all the usual checklist to-dos i.e clear cache, routes, views, composer autoload -dev, etc and immediately got the error mentioned. Looking at the logs below the first error doesn't make sense to me as I've changed the .env DB credentials from the defaults for localhost to the ones I've made on the server. I have also confirmed they aren't hard-coded in the config/database.php file so with all that said can anyone help me understand this log file. The first line specifically makes no sense to me but maybe the problem lies elsewhere.

I also don't know if this is relevant but the logs appearing on my public folder have their file names as the location the app is on my local machine i.e `C:\workspace\portfolio\shop\storage\logs` so maybe its a path issue? Don't know if this helps but the more info I provide and whatnot.

EDIT: SO isn't allowing me to post the full 51 line log here so if it can help I have posted it to [my website](https://derickmasai.com/error-logs/laravel.txt).

```
[2021-05-05 17:16:44] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `shoes` where `tag` = Best Seller) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `shoes` where `tag` = Best Seller) at /home/cruftedc/shushop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678)
[stacktrace]
```

Comment: (a) the configuration is not correct, make sure you've successfully updated your .env file, it is being read correctly and there's no cached configuration. (b) your session storage driver seems to be refering to a `C:\...` path, which is also wrong. However we can't know what the problem with that is without some code

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response. I have mentioned my log files have that path. I did not set this up so I don't know how to change it as I am still relatively new to the Laravel framework. Do you know how to go about this? In the meantime let me try clearing my cache again. Lastly, please advise on the code that may help and I'll post it asap.

Comment: Check your `config/session.php` for what `'storage' =>...` is for the session thing. For the config thing you can do is in your [`public/index.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/index.php) do a `dd(config('database'))` and check the values there (do not share this information though, just take a look at it to see  if the .env file is read correctly)

Comment: No joke I don't have the `'storage' =>...` entry in my `config/session.php` file. Could this be the issue or was it just deprecated?

Comment: it should then use the default which might mean that you hardcoded a base path somewhere. Maybe do a find in your code for that hardcoded path and again check if there's a cached config in `bootstrap/cache`

Comment: Okay. So I've just found the file and you're right it is there. It is actually the reason my logs have the local machine path on my server as well though I did not set this up. I have also some details such as url that do not match my `.env` file. How should I change the path? The store's domain is `shushop.derickmasai.com` if that is relevant

Comment: anything in the `boostrap/cache` folder can be safely deleted (except the .gitignore file). commands like `php artisan config:clear` followed by `php artisan config:cache` will rebuild the cache but you need to run those commands directly on the hosting server, not locally. The site should work fine without a cached config as well but it may be slightly slower

Comment: That worked like a charm. I can't mark this as the solution as it is a comment so I'll just answer it below. Thank you so so much @apokryfos for your patience and for sharing your knowledge with a junior dev. Have a blessed day legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @apokryfos has mentioned in the comments under the question, the solution is simply to delete the files contained in `bootstrap/cache` except .gitignore then run the command `php artisan config:cache` on your server instead of locally. This is what made me have the log file folders with the local machine location as their names.

Deleting these files has indeed cleared the issue and the app is working albeit slower so running the command above really helps. Hope this helps someone else in the future. Happy programming everyone ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not related, but somehow my own server removes the file permissions from the log file. At this point i am assuming i have setup my permission wrong.

a Quickfix would be chmod 775 on specifically the log file.

a better solution would be checking the ownership of the storage directory since it could also produce some other headaches with files, permissions, etc...

Comment: Thank you for the response, Marcel. I've just taken a look at my permissions and they're currently at 755 so I don't think this is the issue.